# How can I create a VPN connection via a startup script?

Tags: vpn, script, boot, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to deploy a VPN connection to all laptops on my Domain via the startup script. It has to be done at startup and not login as the connection has to be available to all users and they don't have admin rights.

I can't find how connections are stored in the registry so I can't export them to a reg file. Can be done via a Batch file, VBScript or AD Group Policy instead?

All my machines are Win XP and we use Server 2003 and 2008 Servers.